# How to add an additional class to each element in the menu-local-task.html.twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

I need to change the admin tab template by adding my wrapper and class to it.

This is the default code:

```
<li{{ attributes.addClass(is_active ? 'is-active') }}>{{ link }}</li>
```

My code:

```
<div {{ .attributes.addClass(is_active ? 'DefTabs__tabItem--active') }}>{{ link }}</div>
```

Currently, the "DefTabs__tabItem--active" class is added to the active link, but I need to add an additional CSS class "DefTabs__tabItem" to each DIV element. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array, ex:

```
{%
    set classes = [   
      is_active ? 'is-active',
      'my-second-class-name',
    ]
%}

<div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ link }}</div>
```

---

> Currently, the "DefTabs__tabItem--active" class is added to the active
> link, but I need to add an additional CSS class "DefTabs__tabItem" to
> each DIV element.

By the way, no need to repeat yourself with the naming, do this:

```
{%
    set classes = [   
      'DefTabs__tabItem',
      is_active ? 'active',
    ]
%}

<div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ link }}</div>
```

Then in CSS you can target the active with `.DefTabs__tabItem.active { ... }`

Comment: Your method works. Could you also suggest how to use the {{ link}} element and display the title and URL separately in the right places?

Comment: I tried this option, it doesn't output anything

Comment: @ВладимирПомелов sorry was guessing, its `{{ link['#title'] }}` and `{{ link['#url'] }}` an upvote to the questions answer would be appriciated 